# Yet another string literal, UDL labyrinth

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

*NOTE: This is MSVC, C++17 question.*

Disclaimer: I know this has been attempted, and yes I was trying to find a relevant SO answer.

I can code the [UDL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal#Literal_operators), to achieve transforming numeric literals to `std::array`, at compile time:

```
    // std::array{ '1','2','3' }
    constexpr auto a_1 = 123_std_char_array;

    // std::array{ '0','x','1','2' }
    constexpr auto a_2 = 0x12_std_char_array;

    // std::array{ '4'.'2','.','1','3' }
    constexpr auto a_3 = 42.13_std_char_array;
```

And this is the UDL, I made:

```
    template< char ... Chs >
inline constexpr decltype(auto) operator"" _std_char_array( )
{
    // append '\0'
    return  std::array { Chs..., char(0) } ;
}
```

Amazing, snazzy, modern, blah,blah,blah ... But.

### The Question

How do I code an UDL to allow for this:

```
    // std::array {'S','t','r','i','n','g'}
    constexpr auto std_char_array_buff_ = 
         "String"_std_char_array ;
```

In MSVC, C++17, please.

### The Confession

I know UDL to "catch" the string literal has to have this footprint:

```
  inline auto operator"" _X( const char*, size_t);
```

I know how to transform string literal to std::array, at compile time. But without UDL. [Please see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/to_array), for inspiration.

Yes, I know C++20 will have UDL template addition, and GCC, clang have something else right now. Although I do not see how is any of that helping me.

And lastly, I know I can do this:

```
     constexpr auto string_view_ = "String"sv ;
```

Comment: *I know how to transform string literal to std::array, at compile time. But without UDL.* Why can't you just call *that* from UDL? Unless you mean transforming `const char[N]` instead of `const char*` and `std::size_t`.

Comment: @Zereges , please show us how you might do that?

Comment: @ChefGladiator, Zerege's probably talking about how `to_array` is implemented, using the `const char (&)[N]` argument, with a deduced template argument `N`, which is neither a valid argument for UDL, nor convertible from `const char*` with `size_t`, even though the `size_t` value is known at compile time.

Comment: @JoelFilho Exactly. Here's the [code](https://godbolt.org/z/zJ5mGw) with interesting MSVC downfalls.

Comment: @JoelFilho yes I understood what is Zereges talking about. Alas, I am bit confused how is this helping us? I am sure many of us are using that kind of code for quite a long time. And I know that can not be somehow "called from UDL" as Zerges suggested. Sorry to be blunt.

Comment: Do you want the trailing `'\0'` or not?  Your code and comment contradict with each other.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this does not seem to be possible in C++17.  A *user-defined-string-literal* can only match `operator""X(str, len)` per [[lex.ext]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.ext#5).  Then, the `len` is a function argument, and function arguments cannot be converted to template arguments.  Just like you can't do this:

```
template <int N>
struct S {};

constexpr auto f(int n)
{
    return S<n>{}; // no, n is not guaranteed to be known at compile time
}
```

`"foo"sv` works because the size isn't a template parameter of `std::basic_string_view`, but a "runtime" property instead which happens to benefit from `constexpr`.  You can't do it with `std::array` because the size is a template parameter of `std::array`.

`make_array` works because it is not a literal operator, so it can take the size as a *template* parameter instead of a *function* parameter.  Then, it can pass the template parameter to `std::array`.  A literal operator can't do that.

---

In C++20, I think we can use a wrapper type like this:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct helper {
    std::array<char, N> string;

    template <std::size_t... Is>
    constexpr helper(const char (&str)[N + 1], std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        :string{str[Is]...}
    {
    }
    constexpr helper(const char (&str)[N + 1])
        :helper{str, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}}
    {
    }
};

template <std::size_t N>
helper(const char (&str)[N]) -> helper<N - 1>;
```

and then use a string literal operator template:

```
template <helper str> // placeholder type for deduction
constexpr auto operator""_S()
{
    return str.string;
}

static_assert("foo"_S == std::array{'f', 'o', 'o'});
```

C++20 is not finalized yet though, so I cannot speak for sure.

Comment: Thanks. Yes this is how (approximately) C++2x might help. Hopefully this will be "voted in" C++20. One of the counter arguments, I actually remember reading was this might "put a pressure on compiler vendors" .. If I remember correctly assumption is that feature might allow some people  to create "loads of text" this way. But, this we can do already. Not sure what is/was the aim of not providing UDL with the simple signature of receiving native array references, since C++11, for example

Comment: @ChefGladiator I think this is what the current draft says, so it probably has already been voted in.  Also, you can upvote the answer (and optionally accept it) if you find it useful, in case you don't know.